# How to shortcut a variable in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm accessing a value object as follows: accounts[accountNum]

I want to do some minor manipulation on this object, ie: increase it by something, etc. Rather than typing "accounts[accountNum] += something" I'd rather do something like this:

```
MemberData account =  accounts[accountNum];
account.balance += something;
```

Ie: "account" should be a direct pointer, reference, or somehow "be equivalent to" typing "accounts[accountNum]". But since this is a value type and not a reference type, it makes a copy and I cannot manipulate that object directly.

All my research on using "ref" seems to talk about using it within method parameters and return types, not in variables. Is there a simple way to shortcut a long variable name whilst still referencing the same object?

**UPDATE:**

Full source code - Please see specifically Line 46 & 51

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

/* * Description of the project:
 * To implement an ATM machine which accepts deposits, withdrawals
 * DEPOSIT / WITHDRAWAL:
 * Account, Amount, Timestamp, TransactionID, Location
 * Keep record of all accounts in TXT file, which is updated after each transaction. Of course in live system DB would be used.
 * Keep another file that logs all transactions. Make it possible to LINQ the log associated with account, to show transaction history.
 * TXT Accounts in form of:
 * Account #, Name, Balance
 * */

namespace ATMProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
//          Globals.DisplayAccounts();
//          Deposit.MakeDeposit(1000009, 500, "sydney");
        }
    }

    static class Deposit
    {
        //TODO Deposit:  * Account #, Amount, Timestamp, TransactionID, Location
        public static void MakeDeposit(long accountNum, long amount, string location)
        {
            string timestamp; 
            string transactionID;
            timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm");
            transactionID = Globals.GenerateValidTransactionID();
            using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(Globals.transactions, true))
            {
                string transactString = $"DEPOSIT| {accountNum}| {amount}| {timestamp}| {transactionID}| {location}";
                sr.WriteLine(transactString);
            }
            Globals.WriteTransactionID(transactionID);
            Dictionary<long, MemberData> accounts = Globals.GenerateAccounts();
            try
            {
                //WORKS
                MemberData account =  accounts[accountNum];
                account.balance += amount;
                accounts[accountNum] = account;

                //DOESN'T BUILD
                //ref MemberData account =  ref accounts[accountNum];

            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Deposit failed, selected account number does not exist in accounts.txt");
            }


        }
    }

    static class Withdraw
    {

    }

    static class CreateAccount
    {
        public static void Create(string name, long StartDeposit)
        {
            long accountNumber;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Globals.accountIter))
            {
                accountNumber = Convert.ToInt64(sr.ReadLine());
                sr.Close();
            }

            using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(Globals.accounts, true))
            {
                string accountAdd = $"{accountNumber}| {name}| {StartDeposit}";
                sr.WriteLine(accountAdd);
                Globals.SetNextAccountNumber();
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully created account #" + accountNumber);
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    struct MemberData
    {
        public long accountNum;
        public string name;
        public long balance;
        public MemberData(long accountNum, string name, long balance)
        {
            this.accountNum = accountNum;
            this.name = name;
            this.balance = balance;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string thisStr = $"Account #: {accountNum}, Name: {name}, Balance: {balance}";
            return thisStr;
        }
    }

    static class Globals
    {
        public static string basepath = "C:\\Users\\root\\RiderProjects\\ConsoleApp1\\ATMProject\\";
        public static string accounts = basepath + "accounts.txt"; //path to all accounts
        public static string transactions = basepath + "transactions.txt"; //path to all accounts
        public static string accountIter = basepath + "accountIter.txt"; //path to the current account iter
        public static string transactIter = basepath + "transactIter.txt"; //path to the current account iter
        //class values

        public static long GetNextAccountNumber() //returns the next available account #
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(accountIter))
                {
                    long currAccountIter = Convert.ToInt64(sr.ReadLine());
                    sr.Close();
                    return currAccountIter;
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public static void SetNextAccountNumber() //increments the account #
        {
            long currAccountIter = GetNextAccountNumber();
            if (currAccountIter == -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not SetNextAccountNumber");
                return;
            } 
            using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(accountIter, false))
            {
                currAccountIter += 1;
                sr.WriteLine(currAccountIter);
                sr.Close();
            }
        }

        public static Dictionary<long, MemberData> GenerateAccounts() //Returns Dictionary in form of <Account Number, MemberData>
        {
            Dictionary<long, MemberData> memberList = new Dictionary<long, MemberData>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(accounts))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var memberSplit = sr.ReadLine().Split("| ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    long accountNum = Convert.ToInt64(memberSplit[0]);
                    string name = memberSplit[1];
                    long balance = Convert.ToInt64(memberSplit[2]);
                    MemberData member = new MemberData(accountNum, name, balance);

                    memberList.Add(accountNum, member);
                }
            }
            return memberList;
        }

        public static void DisplayAccounts()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("List of all Accounts:\n===========");
            foreach (var member in GenerateAccounts())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(member.Value);
            }
        }

        public static string GetTimestamp()
        {
            string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
            return timestamp;
        }

        private static string GetTransactionIter()
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(transactIter))
            {
                string transactionID = sr.ReadLine();
                sr.Close();
                return transactionID;
            }
        }

        public static string GenerateValidTransactionID()
        {
            string IDPart;
            string timestamp = GetTimestamp();
            string transactionID = GetTransactionIter();
            string numberSlice = transactionID.Substring(14);
            string timestampSlice = transactionID.Substring(0, 14);
            if (timestamp == timestampSlice)
            {
                IDPart = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(numberSlice) + 1);
                transactionID = timestamp + IDPart;
            }
            else
            {
                transactionID = timestamp + 0;
            }

            return transactionID;
        }

        public static void WriteTransactionID(string transactionID) //overwrite and write current transactionID to iter
        {
            using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(transactIter, false))
            {
                sr.WriteLine(transactionID);
                sr.Close();
            }
        }

        public static void GenereateAndWriteTransactionID()
        {
            WriteTransactionID(GenerateValidTransactionID());
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: reference the parent object? `var niceName = localVariable.Values.SubArray; niceName.Here += 20;`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns#ref-returns-and-ref-locals-an-example

Answer (score 5):

Since C# 7 you can use [local ref variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns):

```
  ref int niceName = ref localVariable.Values.SubArray.Here;
  niceName += 20;
```

Note that you can not use this in `async` methods. And it does neither work with properties nor indexers (except for arrays).

Comment: Ok this seems perfect syntax except I'm getting an  "[CS0206] A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter". Here is my exact code: ref MemberData account = ref accounts[accountNum];

Comment: @user4779 Just checked it, it does not work with properties, but with indexers it should work  with C#7+ (I think 7.3).

Comment: @user4779 ah no, it works with indexers of arrays, but not with custom indexers. You should clarify your question and show _exactly_ what `Subarray.Here` really is, because this is obviously very relevant for a correct answer.

Comment: Apologies I should have been more thorough. I'm just new to C# and am attempting to write a simple "ATM" app as a learning experience. I've added the full source code. Manually copying the value back into the array is a fine solution but I was just curious if I could somehow alias the variable directly.